# is there any way to translate web page language, or translating scraped data while scraping using scrapy?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

i am going to scrape dintex.net website in english laguage, but can't find any way to convert scraped data in English language. I also used googletans but it also shows error, so is there any other way to convert that page or data to English?

```
import scrapy
from googletrans import Translator
class DtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'dt'
start_urls = ['http://www.dintex.net']

def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.xpath('//*[@class="listing-btn btn btn-primary btn-block w-100"]/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

    np = response.xpath('//*[@class="page-item"]/a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
    ap = response.urljoin(np)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=ap,callback=self.parse)

def parse_details(self,response):
    Title = response.xpath('//*[@class="show-info__title"]/text()').extract_first()
    Location = response.xpath('//*[@class="show-info__location"]/p/text()').extract_first()
    Contact = response.xpath('//*[@class="show-info__contact-details__phone-link"]/text()').extract_first()
    Contact = Contact.replace('Whatsapp ','')
    Description = response.xpath('//*[@class="show-info__section-text"]/p/text()').extract_first()
    Manufacture = response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Fabricante")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract_first()
    Model = response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Modelo")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract_first()
    Year = response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Año")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract_first()
    Condition = response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Condición")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract_first()
    img = response.xpath('//*[@class="gallery__item"]/img/@src').extract_first()
    thumbs =  response.xpath('//img/@lazy-src').extract()

    #t = Translator()
    #Title = t.translate(Title).text
    #Location = t.translate(Location).text
    #Contact = t.translate(Contact).text
    #Description = t.translate(Description).text
    #Manufacture = t.translate(Manufacture).text
    #Model = t.translate(Model).text
    #Year = t.translate(Year).text
    #Condition = t.translate(Condition).text

    yield{'Title': Title,
    'Location' : Location,
    'Contact' : Contact,
    'Description' : Description,
    'Manufacture' : Manufacture,
    'Model' : Model,
    'Year' : Year,
    'Condition' : Condition,
    'Img' : img,
    'Thums' : thumbs
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should send this cookie with your requests

```
googtrans=/es/en
```

As the page allows for localisation depending on selection of the available langauage/region.

You would need to do something like this 
see cookie part from the [scrapy request from scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)

The request you are yielding might need to change something like this(not tested)

```
scrapy.Request(url=url, cookies= {'googletrans': '/es/en'}, callback=self.parse_details)
```